# Jackson with ScalaModule. Deserialize case class with auxiliary constructor

Tags: json, scala, jackson

Basically I want null arrays to be deserialized as empty collection by Jackson with scala module. As I understand this is not implemented right now so I'm looking for a workaround. I think it could work if I have auxiliary constructor with Option[Seq[Any]] parameter. Like this:

```
case class Test (id: Int, seq: Seq[Any]){
    @JsonCreator
    def this(id: Int, seq: Option[Seq[Any]]) = this(id, seq.getOrElse(Seq()))
  }
```

But it doesn't work since Jackson gives me this exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting
>   property-based creators: already had explicitly marked [constructor
>   for com.test.Main$Test, annotations: [null]], encountered [constructor
>   for com.test.Main$Test, annotations: {interface
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator=@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator(mode=DEFAULT)}]

It's interesting that if I remove id field it starts working:

```
case class Test (seq: Seq[Any]){
    @JsonCreator
    def this(seq: Option[Seq[Any]]) = this(seq.getOrElse(Seq()))
  }
```

1. Could somebody explain me what is going on here?
2. Can I have overloaded constructor as json creator with case classes?
3. Maybe you see another workaround to my initial problem(deserializing null as empty collection)?

p.s. about my initial problem. I don't want to have Option[Seq[Any]] and I don't want to have getter because my constructor param will have ugly name like _seq and in scala parameter names is also a public API.